# 1.14 Istio Version deprecation

Tags: version, istio

We are running an istio of version 1.14 in our AKS cluster. From [Supported Releases](https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/#support-status-of-istio-releases) document we can see that END OF LIFE of this version is January 2023.
The support means that the community will produce patch releases for critical issues and offer technical assistance.
**We are wondering is there any strong date when we won`t be able to run 1.14 version?** Because from the above document we can see that only support and bug fixes wont be available after end of life.
Maybe there are some manuals that describe this?

Thank you

Tried to go through Istio Documentation (Supported Releases)

Answer (score 0):

You can stay at 1.14 as long as the images can be pulled from the official registry. You could also mirror them into your own registry to be completely independent.

Have said that you shouldn't do that. You won't get any security fixes and if you need to update because of any issue, you might need to update over multiple versions (e.g. 1.14 -> 1.19), having to update multiple minor versions one by one (1.14 -> 1.15 -> 1.16 -> 1.17 -> 1.18 -> 1.19). Jumping multiple versions isn't supported so you would risk damaging your mesh (though you can jump 2 minor versions if you're using revision based deployment).

The release schedule of istio can be quite tough, but trying to stay up to date as close as possible can save you a lot of trouble.